# After Migration From dev, Only my Links to the Homepage Still Redirect to dev

Tags: database, redirect, homepage, migration, home-url

I'm migrating one of my WordPress sites from a development version to the live version. The problem I'm having is with **just the homepage links**.

- the homepage link in the masthead is redirecting to the dev version.
- type the homepage URL into the browser, it redirects to dev.
- click the 'visit site' link in wp-admin, it redirects to dev.

The **reasons might be** because the migration didn't replace links in the database tables. And! Just to make it more interesting, my first migration failed. So, for a week I redirected the URL in cPanel to the dev version. I've since deleted this redirection, and every page is OK but home.

For a little context, lets say the live site URL is: `http://x.tna.com`
And the dev site is: `http://dev.x.tna.com`. That's the same for the server directories: `live.x` and `dev.x`. I also used git so I have a repo `git.x`. There are two databases, `tna_x` and `tna_x_dev`.

**I've remade the entire migration**, including:

1. (on local using vim) verify all the **links in the database** (download to local, find and replace all URL subdomain instances of `dev.` with empty string)
2. (cPanel/subdomains) **Deleted redirection** to `dev.x.tna.com`.
3. (cPanel/Cache Settings) **Disable cache** for subdomain `x.tna.com`.
4. (WordPress Admin, Settings > General) Verify settings reflect the correct URL.
5. (SSH) I **searched in WordPress files**, `grep -R dev`, and didn't find anything
6. (phpMyAdmin) I **queried the database** for `dev`, and didn't find anything.
7. (Wordpress Admin, Settings > Permalinks) Chnage permalink settings.
8. (local browser) delete site cookies

All non-homepage links in `x.tna.com`  are fine.  I also **have access** `wp-admin` and add content and do other stuff.

**Where is this setting hiding?**

// Edit. I added #7 & #8; The `.htaccess` file was unchanged, but I recreated to be sure. And I thought maybe it could be the browser, so I added #8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have invalid URLs in the database, however, it's also entirely possible to have a hard-coded URL in somewhere in the theme or perhaps a plugin, or even `.htaccess`.

You could always search your entire database for the URL, and make adjustments manually. However, please note that if you make any adjustments to a URL within serialization, you should de-serialize it, make your adjustment, then re-serialize it again, before making the update in the database.

If you want a more automated approach to search and replace all occurrences of a string (A/K/A - replacing URLs), you should take a look at WP CLI.

- [WP-CLI Handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/)
- [WP-CLI Commands :: `wp search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/)

To further troubleshoot...

- Disable all plugins.
- Make sure all drop-ins are removed for testing purposes.
- Verify there's no `cache` subdirectory in the directory
  `./wp-content/`.
- Verify [contents of
  `.htaccess`](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) in the root
  directory of WordPress.
- Verify contents of `wp-config.php` file in the root directory of
  WordPress.
- Clear browser temporary files and caches or just try another browser.

Comment: Hmm. I thought #1, #5, and #6 would have covered URLs in the database and plugins. No?

Comment: @xtian Thanks for accepting my solution. Could you please comment with what the problem was?

Comment: Of course. As I commented in the OP update, I explicitly did #7 and #8 again, but the problem still didn't go away. Nevertheless, Firefox was still displaying the redirection. Then I tried Chrome. Dammit. Firefox is still fracked, but Chrome shows it's only the browser. Thanks for your help. When you cover all the bases, things are supposed to work. I can't imagine what else I need to do to Firefox to get it to behave.